# Looking to stack columns vertically on mobile devices using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

How can I make these columns stack vertically when the screen size is below 600px or so?

I've attached an image of how it's looking at 320px (very squished).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 offset-sm-2">
            <p></p>
        </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 offset-sm-2">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 offset-sm-2">
            <p></p>
        </div>

    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 offset-sm-2">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing several closing div tags. You should put columns in a single row instead of using a new row each time since you're only using 1/3 of the Bootstrap grid.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/0RCKNb2fvY

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I should be wrapping the content in a separate div below the col div, and making sure that they all the content is part of the same row.